# Create horizontal website

Tags: html

I have a series of images I want to be displayed on my web page horizontally. How can I achieve this in HTML? Surprisingly searches for this query seem to leave me empty handed. I would think the solution would be fairly simple and straight forward.

Comment: just make the width of the containing box large enough

Comment: try adding `white-space:nowrap` on the container div which holds the images

Comment: And add 'float:left' to the images...

Comment: It works! How come none of you submitted your answers as well...answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add white-space:nowrap on the container div which holds the images

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/t7tjhpp4/)**

```css
.container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  overflow: auto;
}
.container div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/100x200) no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, I got it working. That was a lot easier than I thought. Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 2):

Place your images in a block with `white-space:nowrap` to stop them wrapping and `overflow:auto` to make it scrollable:

```css
#images {white-space:nowrap; overflow:auto;}
#images img {width:180px; height:180px;}
```

```html
<div id="images">
    <img src="" alt="1" />
    <img src="" alt="2" />
    <img src="" alt="3" />
    <img src="" alt="4" />
    <img src="" alt="5" />
    <img src="" alt="6" />
    <img src="" alt="7" />
    <img src="" alt="8" />
    <img src="" alt="9" />
    <img src="" alt="10" />
    <img src="" alt="11" />
    <img src="" alt="12" />
    <img src="" alt="13" />
    <img src="" alt="14" />
</div>
```